# How to pick the next Datetime for same AgentID in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, window-functions

The first column (CALL_START) is time on which somebody of some particular ID (CALLER_ID) made a call. [see snippet of data here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOeGB.png)

Now I want to pick out the next call of the same ID and store it in a new column named as 'Next_call' and if there is no next call it stores NULL.

So this is the result that I want below.

```
CALL_START             NEXT_CALL             CALLER_ID
2017-01-14 10:50:38   NULL                  2837061
2017-01-14 10:21:03   2017-01-14 10:50:38   2837061
```

The CALLER_ID should be same to find the next call, so I have to find a next call according to each ID.

I have tried this so far.

```
select CALL_START, CALLER_ID
from call_data.records
where CALL_START > (select CALL_START from call_data.records group by CALLER_ID)
;
```

This query does not work for me and I am not sure how to do it exactly as I am learning sql
records is a temp table which I joined using different table's data.

I am new to learning SQL, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `lead()|`:

```
select 
    call_start, 
    lead(call_start) over(partition by caller_id order by call_start) next_call, 
    caller_id
from call_data.records r
```

In earlier versions, one alternative is a subquery:

```
select
    call_start,
    (
        select min(r1.call_start) 
        from call_data.records r1 
        where r1.caller_id = r.caller_id and r1.call_start > r.call_start
    )  next_call,
    caller_id
from call_data.records r
```

Comment: The first query gives me the next_call column but the caller_id shows null in all rows

Comment: Please tell me why are there 2 from statements in the second query? It shows me a syntax error.

Comment: @Chloe: that was a typo. Fixed

Comment: I don't think this can work as records is a temporary table. I mentioned above. Can you tell me an alternate way of LEAD() using rownumber?